# Как правильно сделать разметку разделов сайта Schema.org?

Tags: reactjs, seo, schema.org

Хочу сделать разметку небольшого сайта гостиницы с помощью Schema.org.
Нашел в сети много информации, но не нашел примеров разметки полноценного сайта и его разделов, где есть все, что меня интересует.
Хотел бы задать несколько вопросов.

1) Главную страницу я обернул в

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel">
</div>
```

Внутренние теги, такие как адрес, название и тд, тоже размечены (itemprop="") Правильно ли это?

2) Более сложный (для меня) вопрос. Мне нужно, чтобы поисковая система создавала быстрые ссылки для разделов сайта (то есть, дополнительные колонки в поисковой выдаче). В документации написано, что быстрые ссылки создаются самой поисковой системой, при условии, что разделы сайта правильно оформлены с помощью разметки.
Так вот, - а как должны быть размечены другие разделы сайта?
Например, разделы "Номера", "Новости", "Цены" и т.д.
Их тоже надо обернуть в **http://schema.org/Hotel** ?

3) Еще более сложный вопрос. На клиенте у меня **React (Single-page application)**. Как известно, у SPA есть проблемы с индексацией. Я решил использовать следующий подход. На клиенте стоит тег

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

А на сервере создать копии страниц с адресом, заканчивающимся на **?_escaped_fragment_=**. То есть, на клиенте ссылки рендерятся с помощью React-router, а копии создавать на сервере с помощью шаблонизатора. Вопрос - можно ли сделать эти копии упрощенными, не содержащими весть контент, без хедера, футера и других фрагментов (так как эти копии нужны только для индексации, создания превью в чатах и т.д)? Надеюсь, этот вопрос понятен.

4) Можно ли не создавать копии для некоторых разделов и ссылок? То есть, индексировать не все ссылки?

**P.S.** Мне было сложно объяснить некоторые вещи. Надеюсь, что тема будет интересна и другим. Хотелось бы разобраться с этим, и получить ответы на все вопросы. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Главную страницу я обернул в
>
> Внутренние
>   теги, такие как адрес, название и тд, тоже размечены (itemprop="")
>   Правильно ли это?

Указанная в вашем примере разметка является микродата т поддерживатеся Гугл. Однако (как известно, дьявол спрятан в деталях), для поиска сущностей в веб Гугл имеет серивс **[Гугл Знаний Граф](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph)**, и **[API этой платформы также использует Schema, но в формате JSON-LD](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/)**. Этот же самый формат **[Гугл рекомендует к использованию](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)**. Может быть полезным использовать формат JSON-LD вместо ваших микродата.

> ...не нашел примеров разметки полноценного сайта и его разделов...

По моему скромному мнению спецификация **[Схемы для типа Отель](https://schema.org/Hotel)** имеет отличные и довольно подробные примеры. Обратите внимание на тот факт что тип Отель явялется более уточненный суб-типом от **[типа Локальный Бизнес, который имеет поддержку Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)**. Вероятно может быть полезным совмещать обе эти спецификации в вашей разработке.

> 2) Более сложный (для меня) вопрос. Мне нужно, чтобы поисковая система
>   создавала быстрые ссылки для разделов сайта (то есть, дополнительные
>   колонки в поисковой выдаче). В документации написано, что быстрые
>   ссылки создаются самой поисковой системой, при условии, что разделы
>   сайта правильно оформлены с помощью разметки. Так вот, - а как должны
>   быть размечены другие разделы сайта? Например, разделы "Номера",
>   "Новости", "Цены" и т.д. Их тоже надо обернуть в
>   http://schema.org/Hotel ?

Проверьте подробное **[руководство Схемы для Разметки Отелей](https://schema.org/docs/hotels.html)** (английский яз.). На мой взгляд в этом руководстве все подробно изложено.

> ...на сервере создать копии страниц с адресом, заканчивающимся на
>   ?_escaped_fragment_=...

**[Гугл не рекомендует использовать это](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)**.

Обратие внимание на тот факт, что джаваспкптовые вебсайты имеют довольно долгое время для сканирования. Я не знаю как это может отразиться на Реакте, но может быть полезным для вас проверить **[следующую информацию от разработчиков Lighthouse](https://web.dev/javascript-and-google-search-io-2019/)**:

> Совместное использование JavaScript и Google Search
>
> Процесс работает так: Googlebot ставит в очередь URL для сканирования.
>
> Затем он получает URL-адреса с HTTP-запросом на основе бюджета обхода.
>
> Робот Googlebot сканирует HTML на наличие ссылок и ставит в очередь
>   обнаруженные ссылки для сканирования.
>
> Затем робот Google помещает страницу в очередь для рендеринга.
>
> Браузер, как можно скорее, отображает страницу, которая включает выполнение JavaScript.
>
> Робот Googlebot использует визуализированный HTML для индексации > страницы.
>
> Making
>   JavaScript and Google Search work together The process works like
>   this: Googlebot queues URLs for crawling. It then fetches the URLs
>   with an HTTP request based on the crawl budget. Googlebot scans the
>   HTML for links and queues the discovered links for crawling. Googlebot
>   then queues the page for rendering. As soon as possible, a headless
>   Chromium instance renders the page, which includes JavaScript
>   execution. Googlebot uses the rendered HTML to index the page.

Для вашего реакта может быть полезным проверить следующие руководства Гугл (опять же на анг.яз.):

- **[Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)**
- **[Fix Search-related JavaScript problem](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/fix-search-javascript)**
- **[Get started with dynamic rendering](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering)**